# Lost my keystore password and key password,. but have the pepk file and the jks file, need to update the app

Tags: android, keystore, jks

I just updated my android studio to 4.0, I didn't store the passwords anywhere., Its just the same .jks key am using to sign the apk, and Now I am not able to generate signed apk. 1 week before I generated the app using the same key, and it worked. Now not., I tried searching in logs. no use,. I tried searching in taskHistory and executionHistory.
Another problem is If I click generate signed apk, nothing is happening now. But I am able to create new keystore and generate the apk.

I just found my keystore password. by typing this command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\try\keystoreone.jks"
```

It asked for keystore password, and I tried one by one, and my usual password worked, the keystore file opened to reveal the details. But how do I find the key alias password?

Comment: you can always create new signing credentials

Comment: But playstore only allows if I sign using the same keystore file. without knowing the password, how can I?

Comment: am sorry, can you please elaborate on create new signing credentials?

Comment: you can always request a new key https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If youre enrolled in App Signing by Google Play then you can just contact support and send them a new pepk or pem otherwise you will have to create a new app.